# Authenticating on each API call

Tags: java, spring-boot

I currently have a Spring service that is authenticated through a login page. The desire now is to have a way to authenticate the user for each API request using a client certificate and private key. I created a POST request to an external endpoint that I am using to authenticate the user. I was able to authenticate a user in an authentication filter, but then it displays a 405 error.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest http_request = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse http_response = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String cert_filename = "certificate.pem";
        File cert_file = new File(cert_filename);

        if(cert_file.createNewFile())
            System.out.println("Successfully created private cert file");
        else
            System.out.println("Cert file could not be created");

        BufferedWriter cert_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cert_filename));
        cert_writer.write(cert);
        cert_writer.close();

        String key_filename = "private_key.key";
        File key_file = new File(key_filename);

        if(key_file.createNewFile())
            System.out.println("Successfully created private key file");
        else
            System.out.println("Key file could not be created");

        BufferedWriter key_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(key_filename));
        key_writer.write(key);
        key_writer.close();

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        processBuilder.command("curl", ..., ...);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        String result = builder.toString();

        System.out.println(result);
        if(result.contains("\"successful\": true")) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password");
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
//            TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse(auth.getDetails().toString());
//            String tokenJsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(tokenResponse);
            http_response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            //http_response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
//            http_response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//            http_response.getWriter().print(tokenJsonResponse);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else{
            http_response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            http_response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

    }
}


@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1000)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    String[] permitted  =  {
            "/login",
            ...
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER");

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(permitted).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/swagger-ui.html", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        http.addFilterAfter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have to use curl for that? Can to make simple call from code?

Comment: And why do you have access to private key?

Comment: I don't have to use curl, but I want to be able to take in the certificate as an input from the user.  I haven't found a way to do this through a simple call without the use of a Java KeyStore.  The private key needs to be passed with the certificate to the external endpoint.

Comment: something is not right. Private key should be never passed out. If you are giving it away for whatever purpose, it is not private anymore

Comment: Is this still an issue if the private key is saved to an environment variable?  The authentication endpoint can only be accessed in this way and I have no control over it as it is an external service I am authenticating to.

Comment: Im not arguing with that, I am just saying that it (giving away the key) makes whole system a pile w c*** and untrustworthy.

Comment: Back to the topic. W here do you have that 405 ?? Maybe its just mapping - you are POSTing on GET endpoint or something similar (thats what error says actually)

Comment: After changing POST to GET and removing the request body parameter it looks like it is working as intended.  Thank you.  I'll also go through the process described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The desire now is to have a way to authenticate the user for each API request using a client certificate and private key

Apparently you are missing some very basic principles how client authentication over ssl works. The idea is that the **client has its keypair (private and public key)** and a certificate which **need to be signed by a trusted certificate authority**.

For the testing purpose you may use a self-signed certificate, just it needs to be trusted (in a truststore), see a blog link bellow.

The authentication will take place on the channel (https) level and the client information (certificate dn,..) are passed by the engine as headers or request context

You may have a look at following blog:  [X.509 Authentication in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security)

I would normally copy the relevant information from an external resource into the answer, but in this case, I would be copying the entire post.

Comment: I would also add that the server must request the client's certificate by having client authentication turned to "optional" or "want".  There are different settings for different types of containers (apache httpd, tomcat, nginx, etc...).  You will need to look up the specific syntax for your container/proxy setup.

Comment: Indeed setting up the X509 authentication depends on the container used and SSL termination point.

Comment: So is using curl's --key argument with a private key bad practice for hitting an endpoint?

Comment: @SomeoneElse it's not just bad practice, it simply won't work. You may try to search / read more about mutual ssl https://medium.com/@niral22/2-way-ssl-with-spring-boot-microservices-2c97c974e83